# How can I get my CoountDownTimer to stop ticking?

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, numberpicker

I'm making a simple timer in Android using a `CountDownTimer` and some `NumberPickers`.  Right now when the user hits my button and the timer is not going it will start, when the hit the same button and timer is counting down it *should* stop.  My problem is that it is not stopping. I call `CountDownTimer.cancel()` but this doesn't seem to do anything, the code in `onTick()` still continues to get executed, meaning the `NumberPickers` are still getting decremented as if the timer is still running.

I'm not sure if it is my code, or that I'm just using the `CountDownTimer` incorrectly. So when I call the `Cancel()` method should the `onTick()` events stop getting triggered? They don't seem to be so how can I do this?

I'll put some of my code here:

Code for my button:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Calculate total time from NumberPickers in seconds
    long startTime = (numberPicker1.getValue() * 60) * 1000 + numberPicker2.getValue() * 1000;
    Log.i(TAG, "Start time: " + startTime + "");

    //Create CountDownTimer with values from NumberPickers
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));    //should be removed

    if(!timerHasStarted) {
        countDownTimer.start();
        timerHasStarted = true;

        //Disable the NumberPickers after 'Start' is pressed
        numberPicker1.setEnabled(false);
        numberPicker2.setEnabled(false);

        startButton.setText(R.string.stop);
    } else {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        //countDownTimer = countDownTimer.pause();
        timerHasStarted = false;

        //Re-enable the NumberPickers after 'Start' is pressed
        numberPicker1.setEnabled(true);
        numberPicker2.setEnabled(true);

        startButton.setText(R.string.restart);
    }
}
```

onTick() code for my timer:

```
 @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        //Decrement the NumberPickers after each second
        if(numberPicker2.getValue() > 0) {
            //When seconds left is greater than 0 decrement seconds
            changeValueByOne(numberPicker2, false);
        }
        else if(numberPicker1.getValue() > 0 && numberPicker2.getValue() <= 0) {
            //Else, if seconds <= 0 and minutes > 0 decrement minutes and reset seconds to 59
            changeValueByOne(numberPicker1, false);
            numberPicker2.setValue(59);
        }
        else if(numberPicker1.getValue() <= 0 && numberPicker2.getValue() <= 0){
            //Else, if both minutes and seconds <= 0 revert back to 0 and finish
            //This should never really happen, but just in case
            numberPicker1.setValue(0);
            numberPicker2.setValue(0);
            Log.i(TAG, "There is a tick when both are 0");
        }

        this.millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**
In your `onClick()` you are creating a new object of `MyCountDownTimer` for every click, without checking the value of `timerHasStarted`.

```
countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
```

and then you are calling cancel() on this new object. Hence your countdown timer does not stop goes on.

**Solution:**

Create `MyCountDownTimer` object only if the value of `timerHasStarted` is false (in if block).

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    //Calculate total time from NumberPickers in seconds
    long startTime = (numberPicker1.getValue() * 60) * 1000 + numberPicker2.getValue() * 1000;
    Log.i(TAG, "Start time: " + startTime + "");        

    if(!timerHasStarted) {

        //Create CountDownTimer with values from NumberPickers
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval); 

        countDownTimer.start();
        timerHasStarted = true;

        //Disable the NumberPickers after 'Start' is pressed
        numberPicker1.setEnabled(false);
        numberPicker2.setEnabled(false);

        startButton.setText(R.string.stop);
    } else {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        //countDownTimer = countDownTimer.pause();
        timerHasStarted = false;

        //Re-enable the NumberPickers after 'Start' is pressed
        numberPicker1.setEnabled(true);
        numberPicker2.setEnabled(true);

        startButton.setText(R.string.restart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course! Can't believe I didn't notice this. Thank you very much!